# What iPhone mail application is this?

Tags: iphone, applications, email

What iPhone application for mail is this please? I don't recognise it, but it seems to be popular in Sweden.

Obviously I have removed the email portion to respect the user's privacy.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [Boxer - Workspace ONE](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boxer-workspace-one/id1087506559?mt=8) app from VMware.